# Apache multiple IPs and VirtualHosts

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have two IPs that I can use on my linode, I have three websites running on the server all on different domains, two of them run also on SSL

Here is the relevant parts of my httpd.conf (running Apache2 on CentOS 6.2):

```
NameVirtualHost 178.79.165.220:80
NameVirtualHost 176.58.116.80:80
NameVirtualHost 176.58.116.80:443
NameVirtualHost 178.79.165.220:443


<VirtualHost 178.79.165.220:80>
  ServerAdmin report@domain3.com
  ServerName  domain3.com
  ServerAlias www.domain3.com
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  DocumentRoot /var/www/domain3.com/public_html/
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /var/www/domain3.com/logs/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/domain3.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 178.79.165.220:80>
  ServerAdmin report@domain1.com
  ServerName  domain1.com
  ServerAlias www.domain1.com
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  DocumentRoot /var/www/domain1.com/public_html/
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /var/www/domain1.com/logs/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/domain1.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 178.79.165.220:443>
  ServerAdmin report@domain1.com
  ServerName  domain1.com
  ServerAlias www.domain1.com
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/domain1.com/domain1.com.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/domain1.com/domain1.com.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/domain1.com/domain1.com.bundle.crt

  DirectoryIndex index.php
  DocumentRoot /var/www/domain1.com/public_html/
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /var/www/domain1.com/logs/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/domain1.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 176.58.116.80:80>
  ServerAdmin info@domain2.com
  ServerName  domain2.com
  ServerAlias www.domain2.com
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  DocumentRoot /var/www/domain2.com/public_html/
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /var/www/domain2.com/logs/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/domain2.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 176.58.116.80:443>
  ServerAdmin info@domain2.com
  ServerName  domain2.com
  ServerAlias www.domain2.com
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/sba/sba.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/sba/sba.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/sba/sba-bundle.crt

  DirectoryIndex index.php
  DocumentRoot /var/www/domain2.com/public_html/
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /var/www/domain2.com/logs/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/domain2.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The issue is that if you go to domain3, you basically get to domain1 for some reason.

Comment: I think what you want is to get another IP address: 1 for each SSL site and one for all sites without SSL enabled.

Comment: @xofer I should be doing exactly that, however the current set up should disqualify the SSL Certificate but still get all the virtual hosts running correctly, or am I wrong?

Comment: Exactly what is the problem you're having?

Comment: @MichaelHampton When navigating to domain3.com I am seeing the domain1.com content for some reason.

Comment: You said that already. But you didn't say whether it was HTTP or HTTPS.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Sorry, I mean when I navigate to http://www.domain3.com I see the content of http://www.domain1.com, so HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
NameVirtualHost 178.79.165.220:80
```

to the configuration.  You currently have `NameVirtualHost *:80`, which isn't relevant to the `178.79.165.220:80` socket that is shared between domain1.com and domain3.com.

Comment: I've tried adding both IPs under two separate lines of ``NameVirtualHost`` and still I'm getting the same behaviour

Comment: +1 `NameVirtualHost x:y` and `<VirtualHost x:y>` must be identical.

Comment: @xofer please see my latest edit, this still shows the same behaviour

Comment: yep saw it, and despite the fact that it didn't solve the problem entirely, your setup wouldn't have worked without it.